# Self Signed CA in jboss server Avoid SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER

Tags: ssl, certificate, self-signed

I have simple app runing on jboss server. I have following certificates:
Self Signed Root CA, intermediate CA 1 (signed by root), intermediate CA 2 (signed by root), .pfx certificate for my webpage. I had created a keystore with my .pfx certificate and added it to correct folder in jboss and modified http connection in `server.xml`  file. Anyway when i acccess webpage i see warning triangle that CA is unknown. My question is how shoudl i configure jboss to make warning disappear? Soudl i add it to the trustore? or only way is to add it to Windows/web browser root store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser's warning page appears because the self-signed certificate is not locally trusted. There is nothing that can be done on the server end to hide this warning.

You must put the certificate in the browser's trust store, or get a certificate from a certificate authority that is already trusted.